# Ubuntu: Run the output of another command

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bash

I have command line that outputs a different command line, for example:

```
> commandlineA param1 param2
  commandlineB param1
```

I would like to have a single command line execution that will run commandlineB with the given parameter(s).

Is there any simple way to do that using a single command line or do I need to run a small bash file that will store the output in a variable and then run it?

Thanks

Comment: Searched for quite a while but I guess I had to post a question to find by myself....$(commandlineA param1 param2) did the job.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You seem to have worked this out yourself, but you can use:

```
$(command parameter1 parameter2)
```

**Edit of edit:** the below is somewhat wrong, whilst it does run the command in a subshell, it turns out that the environment variables will still be available. Sorry for misleading people...

**Edit:** that will run in a subshell, any unexported environment variables won't be used. If you want to run a command in the same shell, you need to use:

```
eval $(command parameter1 parameter2)
```

Another answer given is to pipe through bash itself:

```
echo 'uname -a' | bash
```

That will also execute in a subshell, to run in the same shell you will need:

```
echo 'uname -a' | bash -c
```

Incidentally, you can also use back ticks instead of the $() syntax, but it's [not recommended](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Comment: (1) I don’t know exactly what you mean by “that will run in a subshell”.  Unexported environment variables *will* be used. (2) I don’t see any reason to use `eval` here.  If you have a reason, please explain it.  (3) Your last example (with `-c`) is totally wrong.

Comment: You are correct, I checked again and I was wrong there. When running as a list, the bash shell forks and the environment variables are still available. So you are correct, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
commandlineA param1 param2 | bash
```

Example:

```
echo "uname -a" | bash
```

Output:

```
Linux k1104 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this, however it will spawn another bash shell.

Comment: So will `$(commandlineA param1 param2)`

Comment: @tripleee: You're comparing oranges and pumpkins.  `printf '\143\144\040\057\n' | bash` is ultimately a no-op, because the command gets executed in a new, separate (and transient) shell process.  By contrast, `$(printf '\143\144\040\057\n')` will cause the current, active, interactive shell to change directory.